# Correct use of try catch

Tags: java, try-catch

In a Java program I'm writing, I have a set of three pairs of textfields (they take scores from a badminton game). However, in a match, there can be either 2 or 3 games depending on the outcome. Thus, it's possible that either all 3 pairs of textfields will be used or only two. I don't the user to have to indicate the number of scores (too time consuming when entering lots of scores) so I used this.

```
    int[][] scores = new int[3][2];
    for(int i = 0;i < scores.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < scores[i].length;j++){
            try{
                scores[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(mm.getDoublesTextField(i, j).getText());
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                scores[i][j] = -1; //set to negative if game not played
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it correct to use a negative integers and thus a try catch to solve this problem or is there a more conventional/efficient way?

Comment: why not? I think that should be ok.

Comment: It's your code. Non-valid numbers are for you to define. There is no standard.

Comment: I would definitely keep the three pairs of text fields but would check for empty pairs **before** converting the values to `int`.  This would allow you to handle cases where the first row has scores and the second is empty. Or when one side's score is left empty, or any other invalid combination. If a pair is valid, I would then parse them into `int`s and add them to an `ArrayList`. But in simple cases like this it might just be too much work.

Answer (score 0):

Array in Java has always the same length, you should use dinamic size structure like Map, List, etc..

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put(12,1);
```

There is a example (not mine). Hope it can help you.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "Casillas");     map.put(15, "Ramos");
map.put(3, "Pique");        map.put(5, "Puyol");
map.put(11, "Capdevila");   map.put(14, "Xabi Alonso");
map.put(16, "Busquets");    map.put(8, "Xavi Hernandez");
map.put(18, "Pedrito");     map.put(6, "Iniesta");
map.put(7, "Villa");

// Imprimimos el Map con un Iterador
Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  Integer key = it.next();
  System.out.println("Clave: " + key + " -> Valor: " + map.get(key));
}
```

This is the output:

```
Clave: 16 -> Valor: Busquets
Clave: 1  -> Valor: Casillas
Clave: 18 -> Valor: Pedrito
Clave: 3  -> Valor: Pique
Clave: 5  -> Valor: Puyol
Clave: 6  -> Valor: Iniesta
Clave: 7  -> Valor: Villa
Clave: 8  -> Valor: Xavi Hernandez
Clave: 11 -> Valor: Capdevila
Clave: 14 -> Valor: Xabi Alonso
Clave: 15 -> Valor: Ramos
```

Comment: does this answer the question?

Comment: A  `HashMap` is a terrible idea. What if the two sets end up 15-4 and 15-6 respectively?

Comment: I think that fix the problem... :S